# macOS Sierra / Copy Disc via Disc Utility not working

Tags: macos, disk-utility

I'm trying to copy a DVD as an image via the Disc Utility - yesterday it worked (same DVD), but now I get the error message on all discs:

> Could not finished (com.apple.diskutility-Error 3)
>
> Stopped with Error 13 (translated).

Does anyone have the same issue? I´m really suprised that it worked yesterday, but not today. I already did a couple of restarts without any luck.